# Can't find a record in a SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my application, I create a table for my database like this :

```
    String action;

    action= "CREATE TABLE ";
    action+=TABLE_LIEUX;
    action+="(Name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);";
    base.execSQL(action);
```

I then add a record to this table with :

```
    ContentValues valeur;
    long InsertLine=-10;

    valeur=new ContentValues(1);
    valeur.put("Name","'"+name+"'");
    InsertLine=getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_LIEUX,null,valeur);
```

The value I get for `InsertLine` is 1, as expected. But when I try to search for the row added with :

```
            result=(SQLiteCursor)getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_LIEUX,null,"Name='"+name+"'",null,null,null,null);
```

the `SQLiteCursor` result I get has a length of -1. And when I try to add the row again, I get an `SQLiteException` which indicates the row should be unique (so, despite the result of the search, the row is already in the database).

Any idea?

Comment: You do not have a Name column.

Comment: In the create table you use "Nom" in your query you use "Name"...

Comment: @Frank got the problem.

Comment: This is not the problem : I just forgot to translate the original column name used in the first block code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must force the `Cursor` to read the returned data (by calling `moveToFirst` or something like that) before you can get the cursor's record count.

Furthermore, you must not quote values when using the `ContentValues` `put` function; the value in the database now contains superfluous quotes.

Comment: With the `moveToFirst`statement added, the `Cursor`'s count is 0 instead of being -1 as it used to be. But it is not 1 as it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Why did you cast your query result to (SQLiteCursor)?
Query statements always return a Cursor object so bother with the cast.

```
 Cursor result = getWritableDatabase().
 query(TABLE_LIEUX, null, "Name='"+name+
"'", null, null, null, null);

String mString;

if(result != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
     mString = result.getString(result.
 getColumnIndex("Name"));
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: @Zelig63 the problem lies with your content values statement.
you should've written
     valeur.put("Name", name);
there's no need for the single quotes.
the single quotes are only needed in the query statement.